# Receiving multiple share targets on the same Android app

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to allow people to share images and text to my app. When someone shares an image, they have the choice to share it to Page A or Page B. It's similar to what Facebook does below:

[image: Share to apps]

I have looked at [Android's official documentation on sharing](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive). It doesn't seem to explain anything on multiple share targets, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Share your findings/work first and the point where you feel unsure

Comment: Your sharing options depends on what you actually want to share. There is no point in sharing with Gmail an web address, as an example.

Comment: It's not about the type of content, but trying to have multiple buttons to receive the same type of content.